# OpenCV Divide edges evenly and get dominant

Tags: opencv, image-processing

What would the most efficient way to  divide edged and get mean color of each section ?
Something like on the picture, but let's assume sections are even.
Parameters I need is `x = 13` (how many sections in X axis), `y=8` (how many sections in Y axis) `w=20` (width/depth of the section)
Then I need dominant color of each of that - I don't need to save dividers or have output image, I just need that dominant colors of each of those but in known to me order.

Is there some magic that openCV can do ?
I will be doing it in nodeJS but language doesn't matter, I care more about the approach I think.

So my idea was to have for loop for each of the edge, then get Rect Mat of and dominant of that Mat,
So in total I would have 4 "for" loops ( or maybe actually 2 for loops, with bottom-top and left-right section?)

I have a feeling that OpenCV might have some magic tools for that.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You won't like it, but so far I haven't try anything yet, just looking on how to do it first 
But I will probably do something like this https://answers.opencv.org/question/53694/divide-an-image-into-lower-regions/
Except I will try to only do edges. But somehow I have a feeling it doesn't suit to what I am trying to achieve.